# pushcrew - send notification with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

This is the code:

```
    $title = 'Du hast neue Nachricht';
    $message = 'Besuch meine Website';
    $url = 'https://www.bla.com';
    $subscriberId = 'xxx51a002dec08a1690fcbe6e';

    $apiToken = 'xxxe0b282d9c886456de0e294ad';

    $curlUrl = 'https://pushcrew.com/api/v1/send/individual/';

    //set POST variables
    $fields = array(
      'title' => $title,
      'message' => $message,
      'url' => $url,
      'subscriber_id' => $subscriberId
    );

    $httpHeadersArray = Array();
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Authorization: key='.$apiToken;

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPSHEADER, $httpHeadersArray);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $resultArray = json_decode($result, true);

    if($resultArray['status'] == 'success') {
        echo $resultArray['request_id']; //ID of Notification Request
    }
    else if($resultArray['status'] == 'failure')
    {
        echo 'fail';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'dono';
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```

And I get:

```
dono
string(36) "{"message":"You are not authorized"}"
```

And nothing in the console and no other errors. The apitoken is 100% correct. What could be the trouble here? Do I have to wait till pushcrew decide to allow my website or something?

Ignore this: I must add some more text to ask this question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo here:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPSHEADER, $httpHeadersArray);
```

Correct is with

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

(without the `S`)